# Can you a virtual service account access the network in workgroup

Tags: networking, sql-server, database-backup, workgroup

By default SQL Server Uses a virtual account for the sql server service: NT SERVICE \ MSSQLSERVER which is a [Virtual Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#VA_Desc).

I know you can give this account nework access in a domain by adding security to MyDomain\MyComputerName$. Can the same thing be done in a workgroup? I tried to added security to MyWorkGroupName\MyComputerName$ but it won't let me. I want sql server to store backups on the network. If not is my best alternative is just to run SQL Server service as a standard user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this if the machine is in a workgroup. If you have an AD domain, consider adding this server to it. It  will make your life much easier.